# How to format a value returned from database?

Tags: angular

I have an array objects returned from my database , 
one of the fields in the objects  is "arrivalDate" which I need to show in the web.

The problem is that this arrivalDate looks like `2018-12-17T20:45:36.027+00:00` and I would like to change it.

I don't know how to catch the value of this field in the array returned from the database.

This is my array: `items: any[];`

And the field I would like to change is: `arrivalDate`.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you can format the date in template to desired format by applying pipe operator {{item.arrivalDate | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}

Comment: Post the related sample data and expected output with your tried code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Changing in Template
   You can format the date in template to desired format by applying pipe operator

   ```
   {{ item.arrivalDate | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' }}
   ```
2. Changing in code
   If you want to change the value through code, iterate through items array and when you get the property arrival date, change it through the code

   ```
   items.forEach(function(i, e) { if (e == 'arrivalDate') //Parse here new Date("2018-12-17T20:45:36.027+00:00") } );
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the date pipe:

```
{{item.arrivalDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

[More info in documentation DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#datepipe)